# How to fix Unknown compiler option 'importsNotUsedAsValues'. error?

Tags: typescript, docz

I have a project with following config files:

**tsconfig.json** file

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist",
        "module": "esnext",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "rootDir": "./",
        "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./src/@types"],
        "paths": {
            "@src/*": ["src/*"],
            "@images/*": ["src/images/*"],
            "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
            "@pages/*": ["src/pages/*"],
            "@modules/*": ["src/modules/*"],
            "@hooks/*": ["src/hooks/*"],
            "@routing/*": ["src/routing/*"],
            "@utils/*": ["src/utils/*"],
            "@locales/*": ["src/locales/*"],
            "@gql/*": ["src/gql/*"]
        },
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "importsNotUsedAsValues": "preserve",
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "skipLibCheck": false
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "webpack",
        "src/gql/types.ts",
        "src/**/*generated.ts"
    ]
}
```

My **package.json** file with  **"typescript": "4.1.2"**

```
{
    "name": "application",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "application",
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "main": "webpack.config.babel.js",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.babel.js",
        "profile": "webpack --profile --json --config webpack.config.babel.js > ./dist/profile.json && webpack-bundle-analyzer ./dist/profile.json",
        "start:withoutAuth": "webpack serve --env skipAuth --env mode=dev --env isDevServer --env NODE_ENV=local --config webpack.config.babel.js",
        "start": "concurrently \"webpack serve --env mode=dev --env isDevServer --env NODE_ENV=local --config webpack.config.babel.js\" \"yarn build:gql --watch\"",
        "test": "npm run build:messages && jest",
        "test:watch": "npm run build:messages && jest --watch",
        "lint:types": "tsc --noEmit",
        "lint": "eslint 'src/**/*.{js,ts,tsx}' --quiet --fix && npm run lint:types",
        "build:messages": "formatjs extract --out-file extracted.json ./src/**/messages.ts && formatjs compile --out-file ./src/locales/en.json extracted.json",
        "build:gql": "graphql-codegen --config .graphqlrc.js",
        "build:gql:watch": "graphql-codegen --config .graphqlrc.js --watch",
        "fetchToken": "node scripts/fetch-token.js"
    },
    "husky": {
        "hooks": {
            "pre-commit": "lint-staged",
            "post-commit": "git update-index --again"
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@apollo/client": "^3.3.7",
        "@apollo/link-context": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
        "@apollo/link-error": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
        "@react-keycloak/web": "^3.4.0",
        "@types/classnames": "2.2.11",
        "@types/react": "17.0.0",
        "@types/react-dom": "17.0.0",
        "@types/react-router-dom": "5.1.6",
        "classnames": "2.2.6",
        "dayjs": "1.9.7",
        "docz": "latest",
        "graphql": "^15.4.0",
        "keycloak-js": "10.0.2",
        "lodash": "4.17.20",
        "react": "17.0.1",
        "react-dnd": "^11.1.3",
        "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^11.1.3",
        "react-dom": "17.0.1",
        "react-intl": "5.10.6",
        "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "7.12.9",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "~7.12.1",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "~7.12.1",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.12.1",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "~7.12.1",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "~7.8.3",
        "@babel/preset-env": "~7.12.1",
        "@babel/preset-react": "~7.12.1",
        "@babel/register": "^7.12.1",
        "@formatjs/cli": "^2.13.15",
        "@graphql-codegen/add": "^2.0.2",
        "@graphql-codegen/cli": "^1.20.0",
        "@graphql-codegen/near-operation-file-preset": "^1.17.13",
        "@graphql-codegen/typescript": "^1.19.0",
        "@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations": "^1.17.13",
        "@graphql-codegen/typescript-react-apollo": "^2.2.1",
        "@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin": "~0.5.0-beta.0",
        "@svgr/webpack": "5.5.0",
        "@types/enzyme": "^3.10.8",
        "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
        "@types/react-test-renderer": "^17.0.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.8.2",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.8.2",
        "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17": "^0.4.0",
        "babel-eslint": "~10.1.0",
        "babel-loader": "~8.2.1",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "~3.0.0",
        "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
        "core-js": "~3.7.0",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
        "eslint": "7.14.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "~14.2.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb-typescript": "~12.0.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "~6.15.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-alias": "~1.1.2",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "~2.22.1",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "~6.4.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "~7.21.5",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "~4.2.0",
        "eslint-webpack-plugin": "2.4.0",
        "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "~6.0.1",
        "html-loader": "~1.3.2",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "~5.0.0-alpha.6",
        "husky": "~4.3.0",
        "import-sort-style-module-and-prefix": "~0.1.3",
        "jest": "^26.6.3",
        "jest-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
        "lint-staged": "~10.5.0",
        "path": "~0.12.7",
        "prettier": "2.2.0",
        "prettier-plugin-import-sort": "~0.0.6",
        "pretty-quick": "~3.1.0",
        "react-refresh": "~0.9.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "^17.0.1",
        "regenerator-runtime": "~0.13.7",
        "svg-url-loader": "~6.0.0",
        "terser-webpack-plugin": "~5.0.1",
        "ts-jest": "^26.4.4",
        "ts-loader": "~8.0.7",
        "typescript": "4.1.2",
        "url-loader": "~4.1.1",
        "webpack": "5.6.0",
        "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "~4.1.0",
        "webpack-cli": "4.5.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "~3.11.0",
        "webpack-merge": "5.4.0",
        "webpack-shell-plugin-next": "^2.0.8",
        "yargs": "~16.1.0"
    },
    "importSort": {
        ".ts, .tsx": {
            "style": "module-and-prefix",
            "parser": "typescript"
        },
        ".js, .jsx": {
            "style": "module-and-prefix",
            "parser": "babylon"
        }
    }
}
```

I want create documentation for my components and run my [docz](https://www.docz.site/) app:

```
yarn docz dev
```

But it gives me an error:

> ```
>  ERROR 
>
> Failed to process data server
>
>  ERROR 
>
> {
>   file: undefined,
>   start: undefined,
>   length: undefined,
>   messageText: "Unknown compiler option 'importsNotUsedAsValues'.",
>   category: 1,
>   code: 5023,
>   reportsUnnecessary: undefined
> }
>
> not finished source and transform nodes - 1.311s
> ```

If I remove **importsNotUsedAsValues** prop from tsconfig - the error goes away.

But how to handle the error WITH **importsNotUsedAsValues** prop ?

Comment: You're probably running an old version of typescript from the command line. Check your globally installed version or make sure you use a local version in your script

Comment: @AluanHaddad thx for the answer, but there is a prop in my package.json 
        "typescript": "4.1.2",

Comment: Yes I noticed but your script may be invoking a different version of tsc from the command line depending on your environment. Run `tsc -v`

Comment: @AluanHaddad just updated my global version of typescript to 4.1.5, but still the same error (

Comment: If you run `npm run lint:types` is the error raised?

Comment: @AluanHaddad there are plenty of errors in node_modules, but this error did not occure